# How can I get the text cursor position on an editable QWebView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I've tried using the cursor() property on numerous objects including on the QWebView itself, but that seems to return the position of the mouse cursor and not the text cursor.  I'm trying to do something like this...

```
QWebView* view = new QWebView(this);
view->page()->setContentEditable(true);
Point* p = view->cursor().pos(); // mouse cursor!
```